# Debug Django Permission Typo

Tags: django, django-authentication

How can I debug a permission problem in django?

I use code like this:

```
if request.user.has_perm('foo.bar'):
```

How can I know if there is a typo in 'foo.bar'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. Just modify (temporarily) the code of backends.py:

```
--- django/contrib/auth/backends.py (Revision 17045)
+++ django/contrib/auth/backends.py (Arbeitskopie)
@@ -43,6 +43,9 @@
         return user_obj._perm_cache

     def has_perm(self, user_obj, perm):
+        all_perms=[u'%s.%s' % (ct, name) for ct, name in Permission.objects.values_list('content_type__app_label', 'codename')]
+        if not perm in all_perms:
+            raise Exception('Permission %s does not exist. foo permissions: %s' % (perm, [p for p in all_perms if 'foo' in p]))
         if not user_obj.is_active:
             return False
         return perm in self.get_all_permissions(user_obj)
```

Comment: You could write you own backend to do this rather than modifying the Django source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#handling-authorization-in-custom-backends

Answer (score 2):

well i guess you could look at all defined permissions:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
perms = ['%s.%s' % (p.content_type.app_label, p.codename) 
    for p in Permission.objects.all()]

>>> 'foo.bar' in perms
False
```

Comment: The other solution (modifying the django source temporarily) or a custom backend have an advantage: I can run all my unittest and I see if there is any typo.

Comment: well you asked about debugging, not unit testing. nonetheless useful. i definitely recommend custom backend over monkey-patching. that way you can also make sure you only enable it for tests, and not in production